# I can't add stickers anymore to my Trello board

Tags: trello

So weird - today when I went to my Trello board, all the stickers in the side menu are greyed out and I can't add any to cards.

I tried multiple browsers - anyone else?

Comment: I can confirm that neither mine are working, but I can’t find a reason for it.

Comment: Hah, perfect. Just as my friend is trying to introduce me to Trello and all its nifty features, they decide to break the stickers! (not working for us either, in Chrome or Safari on Mac)

Comment: it's fixed now!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what happened, but now it's fixed!  :-)